# How to add project reference to another Project by using latest roslyn api

Tags: c#, roslyn

I am using Following Code but it did not work

```
MSBuildWorkspace workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Solution originalSolution = workspace.OpenSolutionAsync(sol.SolutionPath).Result;
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Solution newSolution = originalSolution;

ProjectReference pr = new ProjectReference(pid);
CodeAnalysis.Project prj = newSolution.Projects.Last();
prj = prj.AddProjectReference(pr);
newSolution = prj.Solution;
workspace.TryApplyChanges(newSolution);
```

Comment: Is an exception being thrown? Or are your changes just not persisting?

Answer (score 2):

MSBuildWorkspace just doesn't support propagating project references back to the project files when you call TryApplyChanges. I see you've filed [the bug](http://roslyn.codeplex.com/workitem/439) on CodePlex, but until that gets fixed (we're open source -- you can fix it too!) there's no workaround. If you only need to *analyze* the world as if that project reference exists, then you don't need to call that and can just use the Solution object you're trying to apply. If your goal is just to edit project files, another option is to use the MSBuild or XML APIs of your choice to directly manipulate the project files.

Comment: Malinkwski Is it possible to add netmodule as reference?

Comment: You can add them programmatically as a metadata reference through the Roslyn APIs. I have no idea how well they're supported through MSBuild.